# Using an arraylist as the content for a spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, spinner

Ive looked everywhere and cannot find a way to use Java style Lists as the content for a spinner! All I can find is how to do it with string-arrays in xml files. Does anyone know how to do this, this is the code I have but it does not work because it is the wrong second argument.

**My code**

```
    List<String> workoutArray= spinnerArray.workoutArray;
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerExercise1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            workoutArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it causes a crash when I implement it this way:`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, workoutArray);`

Comment: What crash does it cause?  Also I don't know why that answer suggests `getApplicationContext()`, just use `getContext()` - it's far more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to create the Array Adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,workoutArray)
```

Comment: This fixes the failure to build, however it crashes the activity, should i be changing the second argument?

Comment: Yes, you can change the second argument. Also, replace first argument this with YourActivity.this . If you still face any issue, please post it here.

Comment: So I replaced the first argument giving me `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(WorkoutsCreater.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,workoutArray);` The IDE likes it but when the activity launches it crashes again                The error code: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.workoutapp.WorkoutsCreater.onCreate(WorkoutsCreater.java:30)

Comment: I should add that line 28 is the code I pasted

Comment: Looks like problem is with your spinner, Could you please confirm your xml file for WorkoutsCreater activity actually contains a spinner with id R.id.spinnerExercise1?

Comment: Yes, this is the code for it `<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerExercise1"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NameWorkoutInput" />`

Comment: OMG i'm so stupid! I put the code ABOVE onCreate. Sorry about that, and thanks for your help! It works perfectly now!